# python: combine two nested dictionaries with dictionaries as values of the top level keys

Tags: python

I'd like to combine two nested dictionaries

```
d1 = {"admin": {"key1": "v2"}}
d2 = {"admin": {"key2": "v3"},
      "user": {"something": "else"}}
```

This should be combine to:

```
d = {"admin": {"key1": "v2",
               "key2": "v3"},
     "user": {"something": "else"}}
```

Is there an easy way to do it other than iterating over the first key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only one level of nesting:

```
>>> d1 = {"admin": {"key1": "v2"}}
>>> d2 = {"admin": {"key2": "v3"},
...       "user": {"something": "else"}}
>>> keys = list(d1) + list(d2)
>>> d = {k: dict(d1.get(k, {}).items() + d2.get(k, {}).items()) for k in keys}
>>> d
{'admin': {'key1': 'v2', 'key2': 'v3'}, 'user': {'something': 'else'}}
```

Deeper nesting will need recursion.

Comment: Cool. I wasn't aware I can do "list" comprehension for dicts.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `defaultdict` to have every value of first level as a `dict`. After you can use `update()` from dict.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> d1 = {"admin": {"key1": "v2"}}
>>> d2 = {"admin": {"key2": "v3"},
...       "user": {"something": "else"}}
>>> for dd in [d1,d2]:
...     for k,v in dd.items():
...         d[k].update(v)
... 
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'admin': {'key2': 'v3', 'key1': 'v2'}, 'user': {'something': 'else'}})
```

Or in a more compact form you can use `map()`... really I don't like it but is a chance

```
>>> for dd in [d1,d2]:
...     map(lambda x:d[x[0]].update(x[1]),dd.items())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
new_d = defaultdict(dict)

for k,v in chain(d1.iteritems(),d2.iteritems()):
    new_d[k].update(v)
print(new_d)
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {'admin': {'key2': 'v3', 'key1': 'v2'}, 'user': {'something': 'else'}})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from copy import deepcopy

d1 = {"admin": {"key1": "v2"}}
d2 = {"admin": {"key2": "v3"},
      "user": {"something": "else"}}

def merge(one, two):
    if isinstance(two, dict):
        result = deepcopy(one)
        for key, value in two.iteritems():
            if key in result and isinstance(result[key], dict):
                result[key] = merge(result[key], value)
            else:
                result[key] = deepcopy(value)
        return result
    return two

print merge(d1, d2)
```

Output

```
{'admin': {'key2': 'v3', 'key1': 'v2'}, 'user': {'something': 'else'}}
```